# Fill data between points Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Im starting with Matplotlib and I need to re-create a graphic that **X** goes from 1 to 28.
The graphic: [image]

How can I do this graphic with only 6 values, and fill the ones between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please plug-in "exact" values in `x` ans `y`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data, the length of the two lists MUST be the same 
x = [0, 6, 10, 15, 17, 26, 28] 
y = [0, 20, 20, 30, 30, 0, 0] 

# plot the data
plt.plot(x,y) 

# modify the ticks to show directly the values
plt.xticks(x) 
plt.yticks(sorted(set(y))) 

# make a grid
plt.grid(1)

# tell matplotlib "we are done, please show what we have prepared"
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to read the exact values from your image; you'd have to enter the correct values yourself. if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 6, 10, 15, 22, 26]
y = [0, 22, 22, 27.5, 27.5, 0]

# optional; making the y axis go up to 45
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([0, 45])

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```